# Clipboard handling in Java

Tags: java, clipboard, awtrobot

Alright, so I have finally swallowed my pride and decided to make an account to ask this question. :P

I haven't been able to find a relevant answer to how Clipboards are handled in Java. My goal is to be able to read, edit, and manipulate the System Clipboard. I created a simple class which is able to simply read the system clipboard at the start of runtime before editing it:

```
import java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard;
import java.awt.datatransfer.ClipboardOwner;
import java.awt.datatransfer.Transferable;
import java.awt.datatransfer.StringSelection;
import java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor;
import java.awt.datatransfer.UnsupportedFlavorException;
import java.awt.Toolkit;

public class regexTester implements ClipboardOwner {

public static void main(String[]args)
{

    String find = "([^/^\\s\\*])([\\'\\s]*)([\\{]+)?("+"Hello[([\\|\\s])?how([\\|\\s])?are([\\|\\s])?you"+"|"+"Hellohowareyou"+")([\\n\\']*)([}]+)?";
    String replace = "$1$2"+"Good day!"+"How are you?"+"$7";
    System.out.println(editClipboard(find, replace));
}

@Override public void lostOwnership(Clipboard aClipboard, Transferable aContents){      
}

public static String editClipboard(String find, String replace)
{
    Clipboard c = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard();
    StringSelection selection;

    try {
        String input = c.getData(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
        selection = new StringSelection(input.replaceAll(find, replace));

        c.setContents(selection, selection);


        return c.getData(java.awt.datatransfer.DataFlavor.stringFlavor).toString();
    } catch(Exception e) {}

    return "";

 }  
}
```

The above works fine. It reads the existing `Clipboard` at the start of runtime, edits it, and manipulates it well.

I created another program (relevant snippet shown below) which copies the System `Clipboard` by creating a [`Robot`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html), which navigates to a website with a text editor and hits Ctrl+C, and then tries to manipulate the clipboard before pasting the result on the webpage. The problem is in the manipulation. No matter what I try, the `Robot` continues to paste the original selection without successfully manipulating the text, as done in my `regexTester` class.

```
public class MacroRun3
{
public static void main(String[]args)
{
    Macro macro = new Macro();
    String link = macro.readNextLine();
    macro.openLink(link);
    macro.wait(1.0);
    macro.clickOnTaskbar(700,350);//click on the text
    macro.selectAll();
    macro.copy();
    macro.editClipboard();
    macro.paste();
}
}
```

The `Macro` object opens a website, copies the text, attempts to edit it exactly as in the above `regexTester` class, and pastes it. The problem is that it does not edit the text, and that it instead pastes the original text without any manipulation. No matter what I try (i.e. implementing `ClipboardOwner` in the `MacroRun3` class, creating a pseudo-clipboard class, etc.), the `Robot` (in `Macro`) does not edit the clipboard!

I have narrowed this down to a couple of possibilities: 1) At some point, `Macro` loses ownership of the `Clipboard`, or 2) Even though I have made the `Clipboard` in `Macro` `static`, `Macro` manipulates a separate instance of `Clipboard` which then does not get copied back to the System. I have attempted to address both cases but I cannot get a handle on the problem.

Please help? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried seeing if there's an exception being thrown? At the moment, you don't provide means to notify yourself if `editClipboard()` fails... This is poor practice as it can leave you debugging code that was given bad input, rather than the code that formed the input. Even `System.out.println(e.toString())` is better than `{}`. And why are you calling `editClipboard()` with no arguments?

Comment: I have. I haven't copied over my entire Macro class, but I have a Sys print very similar to the one you have if an exception is being thrown. It _was_ throwing exceptions, but I handled all of them.

Again, I haven't shown my entire Macro class, but the `editClipboard()` method in `Macro` doesn't need any arguments. I'd surely get a syntax error if that were the case. :)

Comment: I cannot find the `Macro` class in any Java SE documentation (1.7 and 1.8). Is the class which extends `Robot`? According to your question, both `Macro.copy()` and `Macro.paste()` are working fine. Please include your `editClipboard()` method that requires no arguments, as this is almost certainly the function that is failing. Your wording implies that `regexTester` successfully edits the clipboard content, but doesn't explicitly say.

Comment: I apologize for not clarifying. `Macro` is a class that I made, and while it doesn't extend `Robot`, it implements a `Robot` object. I created `Macro` to avoid directly referencing the `Robot` object. There are absolutely no issues in `editClipboard()`, since that prints "Exception" if there is one and I have observed none, but I'll check once more and upload it if necessary. `regexTester` successfully edits the Clipboard content, but only content that has existed on the Clipboard _before_ runtime. Hope I have answered your questions.